# Sending Entire Req Body as JSON object in response

Tags: node.js, json, express

I am learning NodeJs , currently I have just made a middleware function which will send the entire
req object as value of a single key-value pair in json object (I know it is very long ) , but just for learning purpose I did it.

Now I know that req is a object in itself and the value must be a string , so I tried to convert it :-

This is my code

```
function prod (req, res) {
    console.log("This is a body of Req :- " , req );
 
    // const x = JSON.stringify(req);            // Method 1  // throws error of TypeError: Converting circular structure to JSON
    
   // const  x = String(req)                   // Method 2  // displays [object object]  
  
   // const  x = req.toString()                 // Method 3   // displays [object object] 

    res.status(200).json({"Request": `${x}`});
}
module.exports = prod
```

Now I tried these 3 methods as mentioned one by one, but none of them gave desired result.
Method 1 shows `TypeError: Converting circular structure to JSON` whereas other 2 methods displays it as `[object object]`.
However in the `console.log()` line , entire req is printed porperly. Can anyone please tell me why is it not happening in the `response` & also how can I send the entire `req` in json body of `res`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The request and response objects in Express aren’t simple JSON objects like you expect; they’re classes with methods that aren’t serializable. Hence the “converting cyclical structure to JSON” error.

The variable you’re looking for is probably `req.body`, so instead of stringifying the request itself, try `JSON.stringify(req.body)`. That should do the trick.

Also keep in mind that HTTP GET requests don’t have bodies attached typically, so if the route you’re building is for a GET request it may come out as “undefined”.

Comment: If OP is using `res.json()` they won't want `JSON.stringify()` as that will result in double-encoding

Answer (score 1):

**Express.js express.json() Function**

The **express.json()** function is a built-in middleware function in Express. It parses incoming requests with JSON payloads and is based on **body-parser.**

**Syntax:**

```
express.json( [options] )
```

You can also use `app.use(express.json());`
It is convert req.body values in json formate

**Example**

```
const express = require('express');
const app = express();
const PORT = 3000;

app.use(express.json());

app.post('/', function (req, res) {
console.log(req.body.name)
res.end();
})

app.listen(PORT, function (err) {
if (err) console.log(err);
console.log("Server listening on PORT", PORT);
});
```